# View Pager in Recycler View fast sliding glitch

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

Adapter implementation is straight-forward

```
  private Context context;
    private String images[];

    public PagerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setImages(String images[]) {
        this.images = images;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public boolean areArrayTheSame(String images[]) {
        return Arrays.equals(this.images, images);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (images != null) {
            return images.length;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cover_image_item, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.coverImageIv);
        Glide.with(context).load(images[position]).into(imageView);

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }
```

Recycler View initiate and load holder only once

```
mPagerAdapter.setImages(coverPictures);
mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
mCircleIndicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);
```

And the glitch is really weird. First time, it slides okay, but when you scroll down and back up to this view holder, first time slide becomes glitchy. It nearly skips the sliding, making view appear immediately. Although further slides become fine.
Scrolling recycler-view down and back up creates the same scenario.

Any suggestions?

Comment: why are you calling it view pager ? Is it not a simple recycler view ?

Comment: Use this lib https://github.com/lsjwzh/RecyclerViewPager your problem will be solved.

Comment: @UmarHussain 
ViewPager inside the RecyclerView. It's like a banner view for it with swipable views to the side.

Comment: @Avi
I can't use external libs. Also I would like to understand the problem.

Comment: @zeromaro Did you find any solution?

Comment: @bitvale, no. I think it's an android bug itself :/